# How can I make delicious pastries in advance of serving day

Tags: baking, storage-method, freezing, storage

I would like to make some amazing breakfast treats to serve at an event we are hosting but I am part of the event and will be very busy the whole week before.  Does anyone have any ideas for pastries or something that are good for that?

Comment: Hey, recipe requests are generally considered off topic. See: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic  Do you have any starting points for something you'd like to do? Something that you'd like to make, but not sure how to make it shelf stable?

Comment: They're time consuming to make in any quantity but pastries using a yeast-based dough freeze well uncooked. Just take them out of the freezer the night before to prove overnight. We buy them like this, and they're the closest you'll get to getting them still warm from a patisserie.

Answer (score 1):

Yeast donuts thaw beautifully (frozen while very fresh) but if you are amateur, scones are breakfasty and very thaw-friendly.
A little powder sugar pattern will have everyone believing you just took off the apron that morning